# Id-based in-page header link does not display the header on the top

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have

`<h2 id="section_2" >Section 2</h2>`

type anchors in my page and I refer to them as

`http://example.com/page#section_2`

Now, clicking on the link the proper section header appears in my browser but it does not display at the top of the viewport.

How can I make the browser to show the header on the top of the viewport?

I am using Firefox 52.5.0 on CentOS 7, I guess this is not specific to these but it might.

Comment: Did you duplicate IDs on the same page?

Comment: @j08691 : no, I used them once.

Comment: This could happen for many reasons: Maybe the header is located towards the bottom so there's no more page to scroll, then it won't be displayed on the top of the viewport; Or maybe you have duplicated IDs/names in the code; Or maybe there's some lazy/slow loading, the browser scrolls correctly but them something (e.g. an image) loads pushing the content down... Just to name a few. With the information provided in the question, it is impossible to replicate the problem or know why it is happening. Try creating a [mcve] so we can see it.